# Using MurkAPI through Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am wanting to use MurkAPI through my Discord bot.

I want to somehow get https://murkapi.com/docs.php the python example working on my Discord bot so when someone types $fact in the server, it shows them a fact.

Comment: Have you written any code?  If so, can you share it with an explanation of how it's not performing like it should?

Comment: I've not written any as I have tried and all messes up for me. I can give you another command I have so you get an idea?

Comment: Well what part are you finding difficult, writing the command or hitting the API?

Comment: Both, I am not experienced and trying to learn but cannot do it from scratch without having something to work from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a quick and dirty example of how to use [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to access the endpoints and get data, then send it as a message.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

fact_url = "https://murkapi.com/fact.php?key={}".format(YOUR_API_KEY)

async def fetch_fact(session):
    async with session.get(fact_url) as response:
        return await response.text()

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def fact(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await bot.say(await fetch_fact(session))

bot.run("YOUR DISCORD TOKEN")
```

Comment: Are you hireable to help like paid wise as well, I don't want to keep getting things for free. I gotta learn properly.